# Interview question: is it possible that the correlation of each partition series is negative but the whole series is positive

Tags: correlation

Suppose we have 100 observation point in a time series:

$$[(x_1,y_1),\cdots,(x_{100},y_{100})].$$

Now we divide the time series into ten segments:

$$[(x_1,y_1),\cdots,(x_{10},y_{10})],\cdots,[(x_{91},y_{91}),\cdots,(x_{100},y_{100})]$$

Is it possible that the correlation between $x$ and $y$ of each segment is negative, however the correlation of the whole time series is positive?

I tried 2 segments case:

$$\dfrac{(x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_{10}y_{10})}{10} - \dfrac{(x_1 + \cdots + x_{10})}{10}\dfrac{(y_1 + \cdots + y_{10})}{10}<0$$
$$\dfrac{(x_{11}y_{11} + \cdots + x_{20}y_{20})}{10} - \dfrac{(x_{11} + \cdots + x_{20})}{10}\dfrac{(y_{11} + \cdots + y_{20})}{10}<0.$$

We want to obtain the result:
$$\dfrac{(x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_{20}y_{20})}{20} - \dfrac{(x_1 + \cdots + x_{20})}{20}\dfrac{(y_1 + \cdots + y_{20})}{20}>0.$$
And we have:
$$(x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_{20}y_{20}) > \dfrac{1}{10}\Big((x_1 + \cdots + x_{10})(y_1 + \cdots + y_{10}) +(x_{11} + \cdots + x_{20})(y_{11} + \cdots + y_{20})\Big).$$

I was stopped here since the inequalities in condition is inverse to the inequality in the expected result and I have no idea for the further conduction.

**Edit:**

I added a graph to illustrate `Simpson's paradox`:
[image]

which can intuitively solve the problem.

Comment: Just think about it.  What does it mean for the whole series to be positively correlated?  What does it mean for partial sequences to be negatively correlated?

Comment: You ask a lot of questions of the same form...getting others to solve these problems for you is no way to learn how to solve them yourself.  Experiment with the problem.  Formulate hypotheses (do you believe the answer to this one is Yes or No?) and try to justify or refute those.

Comment: @lulu I am sorry that, I just conducted from the definition of correlation. But it doesn't seem to work. Do you mean there is a way without calculation?

Comment: Try the following: sketch what a scatter plot for negatively correlated data looks like. Sketch the scatter plot for positively correlated data. Can you build a scatter plot of the second type out of ten scatter plots of the first type? This should help build your intuition without any need for calculations. If you get really stuck, you may wish to look up "Simpson's Paradox".

Comment: Of course there is.  But, again:  when interviewers ask questions like this, they want to see how you approach them.  They want to see ideas, they want to see some effort.  All of that is more important than the underlying question.

Comment: @DavidSheard I mentioned Simpson's Paradox in the interview, which is my first thought.  But cannot properly explain their relation unfortunately.

Comment: If you understand Simpson's Paradox, can you sketch a picture to illustrate how it works, and then extrapolate that picture to an intuitive explanation in your setting?

Comment: @DavidSheard I added the graph to solve the problem. I always thought about the `supersession` in regression rather than the most simple case of `Simpson's Paradox`, which leads my failure of answering the qeustion.